# Ajax post array: Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, arrays, json

I'm trying to send an json-array to the upload.php file. The following error popped up:

> Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

I'v also tried to add `processData: false` but then there's is nothing posted to upload.php.

My code: http://jsfiddle.net/r0330537/86yqj/

HTML

```
<div id="dropzone" class="dropzone">
    Drop uw bestanden en/of zip hier
</div>
```

JQUERY

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
    ...
    function drop(event) {
        //console.log( "drop", event );
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).removeClass("dragging");

        var data = event.dataTransfer,
            fileList = data.files,
            file = new Array();

        for(i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
            file.push( fileList[i] );
        }

        console.log( file );
        // ajax
        $.ajax({    
            type : "POST",
            url : "ajax/upload.php",
            dataType : "json",
            data : { "file": file },
            succes : function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    }

    var dropzone = $( ".dropzone" ).get(0);
    ...
    dropzone.addEventListener( "drop", drop, false );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your event Listener into a function like that

```
 var dropzone = $( ".dropzone" ).get(0);
    dropzone.addEventListener( "dragenter", function(){dragEnter(event)}, false );
    dropzone.addEventListener( "dragexit", function(){dragExit(event)}, false );
    dropzone.addEventListener( "dragover", function(){dragOver(event)}, false );
    dropzone.addEventListener( "drop", function(){drop(event)}, false );
});
```

EDIT : You are missing a lot of code here , and there are a better method to do this approach

Despite that you need to serialize file array to get this work Here is the final edit to your code

```
   $( document ).ready( function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );

    function dragEnter(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).addClass("dragging");
    }
    function dragExit(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).removeClass("dragging");
    }
    function dragOver(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).addClass("dragging");
    }

    function drop(event) {
        //console.log( "drop", event );
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).removeClass("dragging");

        var data = event.dataTransfer,
            fileList = data.files,
            file = new Array();

        for(i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
            file.push( fileList[i] );
        }
        file = JSON.stringify( file);
        console.log( file );
        // ajax
        $.ajax({    
            type : "POST",
            url : "ajax/upload.php",
            dataType : "json",
            data : { "file": file },
            succes : function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    }

    var dropzone = $( ".dropzone" ).get(0);
    dropzone.addEventListener( "dragenter", function(){dragEnter(event)}, false );
    dropzone.addEventListener( "dragexit", function(){dragExit(event)}, false );
    dropzone.addEventListener( "dragover", function(){dragOver(event)}, false );
    dropzone.addEventListener( "drop", function(){drop(event)}, false );
});
```

You can check it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/86yqj/2/)

Sure it will post to desired url , which is not at jsfiddler :)

Comment: I believe that this is not *needed* as you write. can you explain why it is *needed* ? -1

Comment: I've tried doing that but then it ignored theevent.stopPropagation(); event.preventDefault();

Comment: your edit is wrong. there is no global `event`. i think you wanted to do something like `function(ev){dragEnter(ev)}`

Comment: dear Luke as you did -1 without discussion you can search your self why this is needed and for @Miaw check update

Comment: without discussion? and what is with my first comment? is this no attempt on discussion?

Comment: What i mean you did -1 then wrote your comment :)

Comment: @SamyMassoud it works. but it is missing the path to the image, where is it stored?

Comment: what do you mean with `it is missing the path to the image` , it send file to your `PHP code` so you have to store it and know it's path ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, post your code HERE... at least a snippet.

You are putting the `File` Object into the `data` key of the ajax options array. this might cause the problems when serializing the data. put into the `data` key only data, that you need

By the way, uploading just using xhr is possible, but you cannot do it as you do it in your example, unfortunatelly...

please see this answer... [jQuery Ajax File Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload)

Comment: I could do that, but then it still ends up to be an array. And I'll try to remember to put a snippet next time :)

Comment: you can edit your question and put a snippet right now. otherwise this question is just not as it should be. this will ensure that StackOverflow remains as qualitativ as it is right now. Thanks!

Comment: The problem is now that I don't seem t be able to retrieve to url op the dropped file. I've tried looking at FileReader api but i cant figure out how to get the url. Do you know how to do that?